# Accumulate data over several days in sql query

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

I have two tables, the first (T1) is a base number, the first is a base value per symbol:

```
symbol       value
------------ -----
ABC           1000
DEF           2000
```

The second table (T2) s a series of values per date, i.e.:

```
date         symbol value
----------   ------ -----
2011-09-01   ABC      100
2011-09-02   ABC       10
2011-09-03   ABC        1
```

What query would I require to get the accumulated total of the value column added to the initial value in the first column over the several days.  So the output of the query would look something like

```
symbol date       total
------ ---------- ------
ABC    2011-09-01   1100
ABC    2011-09-02   1110
ABC    2011-09-03   1111
```

So its the sum of the inital value in T1 plus the sum of all dates less than the date in that column.

The target database for this is DB2 on iSeries

Comment: I don't know DB2, but the general idea is called the **running total**, SQL Server example: http://geekswithblogs.net/Rhames/archive/2008/10/28/calculating-running-totals-in-sql-server-2005---the-optimal.aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An SQL approach

```
select 
   a.symbol, 
   a.value  --current value
     + COALESCE((select sum(value) 
        from T2 b 
        where 
           b.date < a.date and
           b.symbol=a.symbol
        ),0) --sum of history
     + c.value --initial value
from 
   t2 a join t1 c on (a.symbol = c.symbol)
```

Comment: You need a `COALESCE` on the subselect, or it returns `null` for the first row, not the actual first total.

Comment: This works.  X-Zero is correct, you need a coalesce on the subselect.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [window functions](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0023461.htm):

```
SELECT T1.symbol, T2.date, COALESCE(T1.value, 0)+sum(T2.value) over (PARTITION BY T2.symbol ORDER BY T2.date)
FROM T2
    LEFT JOIN T1 ON T1.symbol = T2.symbol
ORDER BY T1.symbol, T2.date
```

**EDIT**

Works on PostgreSQL, according to DB2 9.7 LUW docs it should work also on DB2.

Comment: -1: This isn't valid syntax (on DB2 at least, and I expect everywhere).  I also do not believe this will correctly generate the desired results.

Comment: Whups: This is potentially invalid syntax in DB2, depending on which hardware and version it's running on - It's not valid on an AS/400 running the iSeries OS, for example.  (Please edit answer so I can remove my too-hasty down-vote)

Comment: I tested in on PostgreSQL 9.0. According to DB2 9.7 LUW documentation it should work there too.

Comment: Yeah, the docs state that it should.  Unfortunately, that's one of the things that hasn't made it's way to the iSeries implementation (well, the iOS version - I expect you could use it on an AIX box), hence my initial confusion.  Sorry about that.  Otherwise, this looks so _wonderfully_ useful...  Although, don't you have the relationship backwards (will always have rows in `T1`, but no in `T2`)?

Comment: I made it like that at first, but then changed so that result matches Todd's example